# Find a homeomorphism from slotted plane to the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying to find a homeomorphism from the slotted plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{\left(x,0\right)|x\leq0\right\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
I have thought about this for a long time, but I'm completely stuck and would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: You say you have thought about this for a long time. What kind of thoughts have you made so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Arthur For instance, I had a hard time thinking of continuous, bijective function from the slotted plane to R^2, I thought maybe I could reverse engineer it and find a continuous function from R^2 to the slotted plane, and then see if the inverse function is bijective and continuous.

Comment: @CrSb0001 I am searching for a continuous, bijective function from the slotted plane described above to R^2, where the inverse function is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly are many examples one could think of. What comes to my mind is the following.

First, treat the slotted plane as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and apply the principal value of the square root.
This results in 'folding out' the plane along the cut to yield the half of the plane where $x>0$. On this restricted domain, (any branch of) the square root is a homeomorphism.

Next, we can apply the (real) natural logarithm to the $x$-coordinate:
$(x,y) \mapsto (\ln(x), y)$.

As a composition of two homeomorphisms, this is again a homeomorphism, with image $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I have not come across the cauchy principal value yet, but thank you very much for sharing this example! How would one apply the principal value of the square root?

Comment: Express a complex number $z$ as $z = r e^{\theta i}$ with $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and, importantly, $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$. Because we are excluding the 'slot' to the left, we actually have $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$. Then the principal branch of the square root is $$z \mapsto r^{\frac12} e^{\frac12 \theta i}.$$